# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rest-framework (unavailable) (from versions: none)

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm a beginner and I'm getting this error, can someone with more experience help me?

- ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
  rest-framework (unavailable) (from versions: none)
- ERROR: No matching distribution found for rest-framework
  (unavailable)
- ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed

I've tried using the commands below but it didn't solve the problem.

> pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi

> pip3 install djangorestframework-jsonapi

> pip install -r requirements.txt --proxy address:port

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

1. python3 --version

   - Python 3.10.6
2. print(django.get_version())

   - 3.2.12
3. pip show djangorestframework

   - Name: djangorestframework  /  Version: 3.14.0
4. cat /etc/os-release

   - PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"

Comment: `Python 3.10` is new version and some modules may still not exists for `Python 3.10` and you should use `Python 3.9`

Comment: I think I need more details on what you are trying to, but from what I understand you're trying to install django rest framework. Try this: `pip install djangorestframework`. also here is a link to the installation section in DRF's [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation)

Comment: Try this: `python3 -m pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error messages says

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rest-framework (unavailable) (from versions: none)

which means that your `requirements.txt` file is listing `rest-framework` as a requirement. However, there is no such module listed on PyPI. Did you mean to use `python-rest-framework` instead, or some other django-specific package?

Fix your `requirements.txt` file to make sure it correctly lists your dependencies, and things should work. To make sure you have the correct package name, it should exist on https://pypi.org. https://pypi.org/search/?q=rest-framework lists a number of possibilities you might have meant to use.

PS: `pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi` already installed module `rest_framework` for me, so maybe the correct replacement for `rest-framework` in your `requirements.txt` is simply `pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi`.

See also: https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#installation

Comment: ** Thank you so much for the feedback above, very useful to me!**

Now I have this error below, could you tell me why?

- ERROR: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Honestly, no, that one's not meaningful to me. You might need to ask it as a separate question.